# Definition of "employer" in developer survey

Tags: discussion, survey, survey-2018

There are several question that refer to "employer" or "employment" status in this year's survey.  There are others that make a clear distinction between a freelancer and an employee.  As a freelancer, I normally consider people I work for as "clients" but there's a fine line - since they are in fact "employing" me.

I've only ever been a freelancer - how should I interpret a question like this:

> When was the last time that you took a job with a new employer?

I can say *"less than a year ago"* or *"more than 4 years ago"* and either one could be correct but I'd really like to know how the survey author(s) intended this question and others like it with respect to freelancers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in the case of freelancers, it would imply a long-term contract that occupied a significant amount of your time, but I've pinged folks to make certain of that.

Comment: If you're a freelancer then you are self-employed.  Presumably you're not on payroll but get paid like a contractor - manage your own taxes, etc.  If you're being hired for contract positions, however - where you *are* on payroll, either full-time or part-time, then you are an employee on a fixed term.  The difference is entirely down to the nature of this relationship.

Comment: As someone who's both been an employee for some employer for years and contractor for each given client for over a year or more, I interpreted this precisely how Tim described... A kind of "I try to do the best for my client or employer" -- treating either as important professionally.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Oh, that's a great question. We wrote these questions thinking about career change, job moves, etc; people in our industry want to understand when, how, why developers make these kinds of big career moves. Given our intention with these questions, I would prefer that respondents interpret this *not* as taking new clients as a freelancer, but deciding to be a freelancer to start with, perhaps as a change from working for a company, or like you, just straight from the beginning of your career.

Thanks for your interest in the survey! I hope that we together can build a great dataset to learn about developer work preferences, along with tech interests and such.

Comment: thanks for clarifying Julia - I wanted to finish the survey move on with my day so made the call to interpret it as Tim mentioned in the comment, which yields quite a different answer.  If there's anyway to update the survey text it might be worth clarifying.  I can't be the only freelancer out there who will misunderstand.  Is there any way for me to change my answers?

Comment: I'll see if we can clarify the questions for the rest of the survey fielding period; I can absolutely understand the confusion. This will be a note for the future.